# Graph, search sort by field of DB

Tags: cosmicmind

i'm not able to sort an array of Entity based on value of BD, this is the example:

```
var storage : [Entity] = []
var date1 = Date.customDate(year: 1950, month: 7, day: 8, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)

let codice : UUID =  UUID()
let user = Entity(type:"pazienti")
user["codice"] = codice.uuidString
user[“name”] = "Mario"
user[“surname”] = "Rossi"
user["date”] = date1
user["note"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx"
storage.append(user)
db.sync()

var appoggio : [Entity] = []
var search = Search<Entity>(graph: db).for(types: "pazienti")
appoggio = search.sync()

storage = appoggio.sorted(by: >)
```

I need to sort array based on field [“surname”], how can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by using the `sorted` function, like:

`appoggio.sorted(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
  return a["prop"] as! Int < b["prop"] as! Int
})`

You will need to change the property name and type to the appropriate one.

Comment: You should mark the answer correct so other know :) Thank you!